# How detect playing video by ioctl?

Tags: video, graphics, ioctl

Is it possible to detect video playing by ioctl in linux. Maybe detect decoding of the video file. How about this is working with flash player and html5 video? 
Can you provide some information how start with this.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to distinguish a video image from a normal graphic, so no, there's no general way of detecting if a video is playing or not, if the video rendering is done in software.

The purpose of `ioctl`s is to communicate with kernel drivers. That has nothing to do with your question.